# The “ResolveLibraryProjectImports” task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.IOException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have the below issue since few days back.

This only happens to Android Project.

Visual Studio 2017 V 15.9.26
[image]
I have tried the following method:

- delete bin and obj folder
- clear cache for visual studio
- repair visual studio
- fresh installation for visual studio

I even downloaded Visual Studio 2019 but i am also having below error when building Android Project.
"System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'different ddll file' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: run processmonitor and look which process has open handles to that file (maybe your used AV suite).

Comment: Hi, does this occurs when launching the project ?

Comment: Hi, this happens when I try to build my project.

Comment: @tim009 Okey, you can have a try with moving the folder of project to another path to check whether it works.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT no luck, even if i moved the project file to my C: drive i am still having the same error, the error for 2017 remain on the classes.jar meanwhile 2019 changes between different dll each time the solution is build

Comment: again, [when in doubt, run processmonitor](https://slideplayer.com/slide/12820824/78/images/20/Process+Monitor+Process+Monitor+is+a+real-time+file%2C+registry%2C+process+and+thread+monitor.+When+in+doubt%2C+run+Process+Monitor%21.jpg)